# How to understand the proof of disjoint closed set with distance $d > 0$

Tags: real-analysis

I am not student in Mathematics.

The following proof comes from the book: `Real Analysis, by Elias and Rami (p.18)`:

[image]

The folloing is my problem:

1. It seems the yellow part implies the result (but it does not prove anything). What is the difference between the yellow part and the conclusion $d(K,F)\geq\delta>0$? (Hope to know the logic of this proof)
2. If no the condition "$K$ is compact", just "$K$ is closed", then there may not exist $\delta_x>0$ such that $d(x,F)>3\delta_x$. Correct?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your second problem. Could you clarify it?

Comment: That $3\delta_x$ exists is due to the fact that $x\in K$ implies $x\notin F$ by the assumption that the sets are **disjoint**, and since $F$ is **closed** its complement is open, so we may find an open ball around $x$ disjoint from $F$. The condition that $K$ is **compact** is only used to reduce the cover to a finite subcover.

Comment: About the first problem, it is a common procedure in these proofs: the point is that here you can take whatever $\delta_x$, so in particular you pick one (in this case $3\delta_x$) that becomes handy to establish the conclusion.

Comment: BTW, the finiteness of the subcover is relevant in order to be able to ensure that $\min(\delta_1,...,\delta_ N)$ is greater than zero. For infinitely many $\delta_x>0$ we would have $\inf(\{\delta_x\})$ which could possibly be zero.

Comment: @Kolmin ,  clearly speaking, can I use the yellow part to prove $d(F,K)>0$?

Comment: What I will say so is because the yellow statement says for each $x\in K$, $d(x,F)>3\delta_x$. So $d(F,K)>0$?  Maybe I am not quite familiar with the way of proof in real analysis.

Comment: The second problem just says if I change the condition to "$K$ is closed" (may not be compact). Then $\delta_x$ may not exist?

Comment: d(x,F)>3δx>δx>0 for each x∈K, hence d(K,F)>0? Why are you not done when you show δx>0 exists via line 1? Is the proof done with just the assertion that "F is closed" and "F and K are disjoint"?

Comment: Example that the distance between 2 closed disjoint sets can be 0 is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125709/example-to-show-the-distance-between-two-closed-sets-can-be-0-even-if-the-two-se).

Comment: @ililil so just confirm your answer. Your answer is that to the line 1(yellow part), we still have to show $\delta_x$ indeed $>0$?

Comment: Similar question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48714/a-and-b-disjoint-a-compact-and-b-closed-implies-there-is-positive-distance-bet) with solution.

Comment: @sleevechen  "the yellow statement says for each $x∈K, d(x,F)>3δ_x$ . So $d(F,K)>0d(F,K)>0$?" No, because the definition of $d(A,B)$ is $inf\{d(x,y)|x∈A, y∈B\}$ while $d(x,B)> \delta_x$ for each $x \in x$ only means $inf\{d(x,y)|y \in B\}> \delta_x$ for each $x \in A$ so $d(A,B)=inf\{d(x,y)|x∈A, y∈B\}=inf\{d(x,B)|x∈A\}$ could still be zero.