# Why this set is closed set?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

$A=\left\{n+\frac{1}{2n}|n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$
Is this set closed? 

I was reading answer form [Example to show the distance between two closed sets can be 0 even if the two sets are disjoint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125709/example-to-show-the-distance-between-two-closed-sets-can-be-0-even-if-the-two-se)
where Nishrito mentioned above set is closed .

But On that account then 
$B=\left\{\frac{1}{2n}|n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$
 This set also become closed but I know which is not as $0$ is limit point of it which is not belong to that set.
Any Help in this regard will be appreciated .

Thanks a lot

Comment: 0 is not a limit point of A.

Comment: but 1 will be limit point then

Comment: $A$ is a discrete subset of $\Bbb R$, just like $\Bbb N$ is.

Comment: 1 isn't either. In fact, A has no limit points at all.

Comment: Since $\lim_n \frac{1}{2n} = 0$ and $0$ is not in $B$, $B$ is not closed.

Comment: Please can you explain ?

Comment: @MathStudent $A=\{3/2,9/4,19/6,\cdots\}$. Observe that $1<3/2<2<9/4<3<19/6<4<\cdots$,

Comment: Can you find a convergent sequence of distinct points in A?

Comment: There is no convergent sub sequence in A

Comment: Exactly. Thus A has no limit points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $A$ is a closed set. It follows from the fact that there is a $r>0$ such that the distance between any two distinct elements of $A$ is greater than $r$ ($\frac15$ will do, for instance). But $B$ is *not* closed and therefore there is no way of deducing that $B$ is closed from the fact that $A$ is closed.

Comment: Discrete sets need not be closed (which you seem to imply)

Comment: Sir Can you explain why Discrete set need not closed? @Wojowu

Comment: @MathStudent The set $\{1/n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is discrete (every singleton is closed) but is not closed in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Wojowu You are right, of course. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The complement of  $A$ is an infinite union of open intervals, so the complement is open which makes $A$ an open set.

Also $0$ is not a limit point of $A$, on the contrary it is an isolated point of $A.$

In fact every point of $A$ is an isolated point.